# How to calculate average minor allele frequency (MAF) difference between two populations (i.e. European, Hispanic)

Tags: bioconductor, plink

The data is present in the PLINK format .bed (individual genotypes), .bim (genetic markers) and .fam (sample IDs and disease phenotype file). I have also separate text files containing information on subjects related to two populations. (i.e. European and Hispanic)

[image: Question related PLINK data]

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to report allele frequencies using `plink` for some European samples
2. Do the same for Hispanic samples
3. Use a software to subtract the two allele frequencies obtained above and obtain the result.

Comment: Hi, I think I kind of understood what you mean. So in PLINK, we use --freq command to find information on frequency. and what software do you recommend to subtract the frequency files of two populations? thank You